# How do I force the width of a UICollectionViewCell dynamically

Tags: ios, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionViewCell that is dynamically sized with auto layout.

```
- (CGSize) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  // Force cell layout and take auto layout height
    [self configureCell:_sizingCell forIndexPath:indexPath];


    return [_sizingCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize];

}
```

This works for resizing but the width takes up way too much space.  I need to force a constraint for width on this based on the screen size and let auto layout figure out the height from there.  How do I go about doing this properly?  I need this to work in iOS 7 and iOS 8.

Comment: Hello, did you manage to solve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

If you haven't already, constrain the leading and trailing edges of your cell to the left and right edges of the collection view. That gives cells a fixed width. The height is trickier. All labels in the cell have to have a row height of 0 and be set to word wrap--you generally don't want to truncate the string or shrink the font size. Next, ensure that all of your items are vertically constrained, but don't give them fixed heights. This will allow them to grow vertically, and as long as they're vertically constrained to the controls above and below them, you should get the effect you want.

Comment: My cell is in it's own separate xib file.  I reuse it across multiple collection view.  Can I constrain just a width on to the cell?  I basically want each cell to have a width of 48% of the collection view width.

Comment: Yes, you can do that from the collection views that contain it.

Comment: In interface builder or programmatically?  Can I get an example of that?

Comment: At the end of the day I'd like them to stack two by two taking most of the available space to do it.  I had the height thing working with auto layout originally until I upgraded Xcode.  Now it seems I have to do auto layout based on my content view instead of the cell itself and I can't get it to do the width and tiling correctly.